# Custom 'p26=' functions

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, email2case

I have created a custom buttom to send an email from a case.  The problem that I've found is that I can get cases sent to 2 different email addresses.  So when the button is clicked I want it to populate the from address (p26=) with the To address the email that was received, not just a specific one that is hard coded.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out awhile ago, but just wanted to update this with the solution.

Parameters in the URL:-

p24 - Additional To Address

template_id - Email Template Id, It can have merge fields.

p3_lkid = whatId ( hidden lookup field) it is must if the merge fields are there in template

p3 = Related to name (input text)

p26 - From Email Address

p5 - BCC email address

save = 0, means send the email automatically and return to retURL ,( leave it if you just need to see the screen with populated fields)

I found this information at: [Forcetips Url Hacks](http://forcetips.blogspot.com/2013/02/url-hack-to-send-email-by-simple-button.html)

Another resource I found was at: [Salesforce Ben Email URL Hacks](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-email-url-hack-tutorial/)

I hope this helps someone in the future.